# Android DatePickerDialog: Set min and max date for selection

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I know there are quite a lot of question for this but none of the solutions are working for me, so this question. I want to restrict user to select date before today, but am not able to do so.

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private OnDateSetListener listener;

    public void setListener(OnDateSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year    = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month   = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day     = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), listener, year, month, day);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

I am showing it as:

```
DatePickerDialogFragment fragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment();
fragment.setListener(dateSetListener);
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Choose booking date");
```

I want the user should not be able to select date before today. As you can see I called `setMinDate()` method with today's time but it as no effect. The dialog shows dates before today as grayed but selectable.

I also tried to sub-class `DatePickerDialog` and override `onDateChanged` as suggested in some stackoverflow answers but without any success.

Comment: not smart complete but onDateSet, should compare result with min and max value

Comment: @Abdullah Did you find any work out for this..?

Comment: @RethinavelPillai I ended up doing what is mentioned in the accepted post.

Comment: check out mycustom datepickerdialog https://github.com/Redman1037/EightFoldsDatePickerDialog

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this method

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year    = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month   = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day     = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), listener, year, month, day);
    Field mDatePickerField;
    try {
            mDatePickerField = dialog.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDatePicker");
            mDatePickerField.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    return dialog;
}
```

instead of your

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year    = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month   = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day     = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), listener, year, month, day);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    return dialog;
}
```

**EDIT1:**

I have also faced this issue that user can select not-selectable dates in `Android L 5.0.2`. Currently there is bug reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=103263&can=1&q=DatePickerDialog&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). It is solved in `Android L 5.1.0`.

For temporary solution of this issue you can compare selected date with current system date and put some condition based on that. I used this as my workaround

**EDIT2:**

add `onDateSent()` method in `DatePickerDialogFragment` and just check if it's earlier than the date you set in `setMinDate()`. If so, then just show the `DatePickerDialog` again.

```
final long today = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            //If user tries to select date in past (or today)
            if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < today)
            {
                //Make them try again
               DatePickerDialogFragment fragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment();
               fragment.setListener(dateSetListener);
               fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Choose booking date");
               Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid date, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                //success
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Eventually I ended up doing the same.

Answer (score 10):

Get System Time and subtract 1 second from It

```
 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year    = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month   = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day     = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

     dialog = new DatePickerDialog(act, listener, year, month, day);
     dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() -1000);
     return dialog;
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 3):

Above API 11 For min date you can use

`android:minDate="mm/dd/yyyy"`
or `setMinDate(long time)`
For Max date

`android:maxDate="mm/dd/yyyy"` // In XML

`setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());`// Current time

Comment: I am calling setMinDate() but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I set the minimum date using the method to the current year which is `2020-05-20` like this

`datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());`

The moment you click the date picker it displays 2020 as the minimum year

I hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the XML File

```
<DatePicker
android:minDate="mm/dd/yyyy"
android:maxDate="mm/dd/yyyy" >
```

ex:

```
android:minDate="10/12/2000"


android:maxDate="10/12/2000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Android DatePickerDialog: Set min and max date for selection to show allowed dates from 16 to 30 Aug 2022.

```
// Month is 0 based for Calendar.
final Calendar cMax = Calendar.getInstance();
// CMax.set(mYear, mMonth-1, mDay)
cMax.set(2022,7,30); // for date 30/Aug/2022
XXDatePicker.setMaxDate(cMax.getTimeInMillis());

final Calendar cMin = Calendar.getInstance();
// CMin.set(mYear, mMonth-1, mDay)
cMin.set(2022,7,16); // for date 16/Aug/2022
XXDatePicker.setMinDate(cMin.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  mdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            //set time zone
            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            int selectedYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int selectedMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int selectedDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(BrandResturant_DetailActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                            mDay = selectedDay;
                            mMonth = selectedMonth;
                            mYear = selectedYear;
                            StringBuilder Date = new StringBuilder("");
                            String conver = Integer.toString(selectedYear);
                            Date.append(conver);
                            Date.append("-");
                            selectedMonth++;
                            conver = Integer.toString(selectedMonth);
                            Date.append(conver);
                            Date.append("-");
                            conver = Integer.toString(selectedDay);
                            Date.append(conver);
                            isDob = true;
                        }
                    }, mDay, mMonth, mYear);

            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());


            
            //Getting Today date to calendar2
            final Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            //Set Minimum date of calendar
            calendar2.set(2021, 1, 3);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar2.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
            datePickerDialog.show();


            //Getting Today date to calendar3
            final Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
            //Set Maximum date of calendar - Method 1
            calendar3.set(2021, 3, 3);
            //Set Maximum One Month date from today(calendar3) date to calendar -Method 2
            //In Place of month u can also set year, day
            //calendar3.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar3.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your code.

Comment: @AshishSharma you can set the  minimum date for selection  by getting the date from the calendar2 or  to set the minimum date  programatically by  calendar2.set(2021, 1, 3) and set the maximum date for selection by setting the  calendar3.set(2021, 3, 3) by programatically or u can also set by month,day, year by specifying month,day,year 
for eg. i'm adding one moth month maximum for calender3 date calendar3.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);