# How to disable past date and restrict user from selecting pass time

Tags: android, datetimepicker

How to setMinDate and time for date and time picker. I tried setting it for date but it does not work. I am not sure how I can set that for Time.

```
private DatePickerDialog showDatePicker() {

    int todaysDate = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(ReminderEditActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            //view.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            updateDateButtonText(); 
        }

    }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 

    return datePicker; 
}

private TimePickerDialog showTimePicker() {

    TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute); 
            updateTimeButtonText(); 
        }
    }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true); 

    return timePicker; 
}
```

Comment: Use this datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(pass your calendar date)

Comment: your calendar date means? "todaysDate "? Can you please tell w.r.t to my code

Comment: yes,search google with these terms you has more option

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051236/android-datepickerdialog-set-min-and-max-date-for-selection

Answer (score 0):

you can set the minDate(type long)  like this

```
showDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```