# how to disable preveious date in a date picker?

Tags: android, datepicker, gregorian-calendar

i am using Gregorian calendar and i need to disable a previous date to till current date in android. i already checked setMinDate method but its not working.. can anyone help me? here is my code..

```
 public void SelectDateTime() {
        final View dialogView = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.date_picker_activate, null);
        DateTimeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
        dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DateTimeDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
                TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
                Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
                        datePicker.getMonth(),
                        datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                        timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                        timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

                datePicker.getMinDate();

                final long today1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000;

                calendar.after(System.currentTimeMillis());

               // datePicker.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: you may use -https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker, and set min and max date and time also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051236/android-datepickerdialog-set-min-and-max-date-for-selection/33051501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        // dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        txt_date.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d/%02d/%d", day, month + 1, year));
    }
}
```

Call this method in side button click like

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

> This line set min date -  dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

and use this to set max date

> dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

Comment: Remove your code and try this code. It is working in my case.

Comment: bro i need time picker along with this calendar .. can u please help me?

Comment: But here txt_date should be static and I don't want to set it static. please give me solution for that

Answer (score 0):

This will disable previouis dates

```
public void showDateToSelect() {
        // Get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        /*DatePicker dialog to select date*/
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        textView.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        /*To show only dates from today to future*/
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

User this library

```
implementation 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.2.1'
```

And initiate with following code

```
 startSingleDateAndTimePickerDialog = new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Builder(context);
            startSingleDateAndTimePickerDialog
                    .bottomSheet()
                    .curved()
                    .displayHours(true)
                    .displayMinutes(true)
                    .minDateRange(new Date(minDate))
                    .defaultDate(new Date(defaultDate))
                    .mustBeOnFuture()
.displayListener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.DisplayListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDisplayed(SingleDateAndTimePicker picker) {
                        //retrieve the SingleDateAndTimePicker
                    }
                })

                .title("Date & Time")
                .listener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSelected(Date date) {

                        Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());



     String dateTime = getDate(date.getTime() / 1000);
textview.settext(dateTime);

                    }
                }).display();






 public static String getDate(long timeStamp) {
        Date time = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyy h:mm a");
        return df2.format(time);
    }
```

Comment: hi bro, here where i have to set the textview date