# How can i disable specific date

Tags: android

I want to disable the specific dates which user selected in another date picker
I mean user selects date in first date in date picker and another date picker sets minimum date?

Comment: please provide some code and explain what exactly is your problem

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051236/android-datepickerdialog-set-min-and-max-date-for-selection link to set minimum data in date picker

Comment: @FalduJaldeep this example set past dates from current system date. i want to disable specic date provided by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality does not available in Android [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker). You need to use a custom date picker.

You can use [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) library, here you can set an option to disable specific dates by using [setDisabledDays()](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#datepickerdialog-setdisableddayscalendar-days) API.

For Example:

```
datePicker.setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days)
```

You need to pass array of `Calendar` days as an parameter which should contains all the disable dates.

Answer (score 1):

you can use setMinDate() function to set the minimum date in date picker.

Comment: Can write an example. suppose i have three int as date month year. Now how can i set min date

Comment: you can use the below code to set minimum date in date picker dialog.

Calendar mCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
mDatePickerDialog.setMinDate(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());